# Android: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzy.

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

I've made a lot of research and I've tried several things like checking if all my imports are in the same version, unistalling Android Studio or copying all the files to another project and I still get this problem when my FirebaseList shows up.

I really do not know what to do.

This is the error I get

```
  Process: com.anonymous, PID: 11244
                                                                       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzy(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/com.anonymous-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes12.dex)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzann.zzug(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzann.zzuf(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.child(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getReference(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.adriacabeza.scoregame.ListAdapter.<init>(ListAdapter.java:34)
                                                                           at com.adriacabeza.scoregame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6760)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2681)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Here is my gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.anonymous"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }    }} dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})


testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'

compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'

annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC1'}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here my Android Manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.adriacabeza.scoregame">
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".CreateActivity"> </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example1.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/api_key"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Bhuvanesh bs has a pretty good suggestion on how to handle the problem in your case. The NoSuchMethodError is _usually_ caused by having a different version of the library at compile time than at runtime. During compilation the compiler checks that all the referenced classes have the same method. If your runtime has different libraries, the methods you use may not exist there, but your code still tries to call them. That's why this Exception happens usually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using latest play service library `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'`. Update your **Google Play service** plugin in your SDK manager. Then clean and rebuild your project.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: did you clean your project?

Comment: Yesterday I reopened the project and everything worked, I guess your solution was correct and the updating hadn't finished when I tried first. 
Thank you very much :)